# Is this definite integral solvable?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int^{1/2}_0 \frac{(e^{1-2v})}{2(1-v)^2}dv$

I tried using the substitution $(1-2v) = ln(t)$

$-2vdv = \frac{1}{t}$dt

Which reduces it to

$\int^{1}_e \frac{-dt}{(1-ln(t))^2}$

But i don't know how to proceed from here

I put the function into graphing software and it didn't give a finite area under the curve between 1 and e

Comment: btw, you forgot to change the limit of the integral after substitution.

Comment: Oh. Edited it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{e^{1-2v}}{2(1-v)^2}\,dv=\frac1e\int_0^{1/2}\frac{e^{2(1-v)}}{2(1-v)^2}\,dv$$
Substitute $u=1-v$:
$$=\frac1e\int_{1/2}^1\frac{e^{2u}}{2u^2}\,du$$
Integrate by parts:
$$=\frac1e\left(\left[-\frac{e^{2u}}{2u}\right]_{1/2}^1-\int_{1/2}^1-\frac{2e^{2u}}{2u}\,du\right)$$
$$=\frac1e\left(e-\frac{e^2}2+\int_{1/2}^1\frac{e^{2u}}{u}\,du\right)$$
$$=1-\frac e2+\frac1e\int_{1/2}^1\frac{e^{2u}}{u}\,du$$
$$=1-\frac e2-\frac1e\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac{e^{-u}}u\,du$$
We now need to use the exponential integral $\operatorname{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}u\,du$:
$$=1-\frac e2+\frac1e(\operatorname{Ei}(2)-\operatorname{Ei}(1))$$